# PowerShell to get all O365 groups

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, office-365, pnp-powershell, office-365-groups

I am working on PowerShell script where I have to get the all the O365 groups using PowerShell with minimal permission.

Please share the supporting articles to get the O365 groups and permission required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `Get-UnifiedGroup` cmdlet to view Microsoft 365 Groups.

Reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-unifiedgroup?view=exchange-ps

Comment: Which minimal permission required to run the command.
As I have only SharePoint Site collection admin.
Client not going to provide high level permission to us

Comment: As SharePoint site collection admin, You can only get users/groups in the site. it's not possible to get the all the O365 groups. You need to have tenant access.

Comment: Thanks for the Updates

Answer (score 1):

To add to the answer above here is an example of a script using Get-UnifiedGroup

```
#Get Credentials to connect
$Credential = Get-Credential
  
#Create the session
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ `
           -Credential $Credential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
  
#Import the session
Import-PSSession $Session -DisableNameChecking
 
#Get all Office 365 Group
Get-UnifiedGroup
 
#Remove the session
Remove-PSSession $Session
```

I am unsure of what permissions are needed however.

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/ is a great resource for all things SharePoint and PowerShell related